# Got an error: module "QtPositioning" plugin "declarative_positioning" not found

Tags: ios, qt, qml, qtquick2

I am using Qt 5.4 on Mac and my target platform is IOS. 
I have a task to add geolocation to my app and I want to use `PositioningSource` component.

I added `import QtPositioning 5.2` to my QML file and `QT += positioning` to my `.pro` file and successfully recompiled it. Anyhow I had an error from a header, when the application run.

Have you any ideas on how I can solve this issue? I saw in qmldir file the string `plugin declarative_positioning`. There are files `libdeclarative_positioning.a`, `libdeclarative_positioning.prl` in directory `~/Qt5.4.0/5.4/ios/qml/QtPositioning`.

The same happens when I add `import QtLocation 5.2` to my QML, but error message is:

> `module "QtLocation" plugin "declarative_location" not found`

The other standard modules, e.g. `QtQuick`, `QtQuick.Controls`, imported in the same QML file work fine.

A little example of my qml code:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2
import QtPositioning 5.2 // an error when this string added: "module "QtPositioning" plugin "declarative_positioning" not found"
//import QtLocation 5.2

Rectangle {
    id: rect
    PositionSource {
        id: src
    }
    Component.onCompleted : console.log(position.coordinate.longitude, " ", src.position.coordinate.latitude)
}
```

Think, that's ok whith the code and problem is in qt some files or maybe ways. That is 5.4 version, installed from automatic dmg...

Now, I tried Flickr example which using QtPositionnig and it's working fine, but my program still not...

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) to reproduce your issue. `Positioning` should work fine on iOS.

Comment: Hello, do you resolved this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you solved it by now, but I just had the same problem and after looking for differences between my project and GeoFlick i found the problem.

your *.pro file should have a line similar to this:

```
QT += qml quick
```

For this to work you would have to add positioning to that list, and other dependencies you might use. For example here is what geoflickr.pro looks like:

```
QT += qml quick network positioning
```